# Method find() not working in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, model, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to use find('list') method, but without success.

When I try to LIST the types of paying, just one table of database was showing correct, another is doing correct SQL but it's returning me null (even with the sql get rows).

If try to read ONE field of Tpagamento, it works
If I change the displayField of Tpagamento to 'id', it works, but the query only show the id.

Here is the scenario:

(Parcelamento and Tpagamento have the same databasefields)

View Method:

```
public function view($id = null) {

    $this->Ordemservico->id = $id;
    if (!$this->Ordemservico->exists()) {
        $this->Session->setFlash('This Order does not exist..','flash_error');
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }

            //Listing all orders // THIS IS WORKING
    $os = $this->Ordemservico->read(null, $id);
    $this->set('os',$os);

    //Listing the types of paying //THIS  IS WORKING
    $this->loadModel('Parcelamento');
    $parcelamentos = $this->Parcelamento->find('list');
    $this->set('parcelamentos',$parcelamentos);


    $this->loadModel('Tpagamento'); // THIS IS NOT WORKING
    $tpagamento = $this->Tpagamento->find('list');
    $this->set('tpagamento ',$tpagamento );

            //Read a specific type of paying, WORK!
    $this->loadModel('Tpagamento'); // THIS IS WORKING
    $tpagamentos = $this->Tpagamento->read(null,'5');
    $this->set('tpagamentos',$tpagamentos);

}
```

OrdemServico Model:

```
class Ordemservico extends AppModel {

    public $displayField = 'cliente_id';

    public $belongsTo = array(      
        'Tpagamento' => array(
            'className' => 'Tpagamento',
            'foreignKey' => 'tpagamento_id',
        ),
        'Parcelamento' => array(
            'className' => 'Parcelamento',
            'foreignKey' => 'parcelamento_id',
        ),
    );

}
```

Tpagamento Model:

```
class Tpagamento extends AppModel {

    public $useTable = 'tpagamentos';

    public $displayField = 'nome';

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Ordemservico' => array(
            'className' => 'Ordemservico',
            'foreignKey' => 'tpagamento_id',
        ),

    );



}
```

Parcelamento Model:

```
class Parcelamento extends AppModel {

    public $displayField = 'nome';

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Ordemservico' => array(
            'className' => 'Ordemservico',
            'foreignKey' => 'parcelamento_id',
        ),

    );



}
```

Generated SQL DUMP:

```
4   SELECT `Parcelamento`.`id`, `Parcelamento`.`nome` FROM `tereza`.`parcelamentos` AS `Parcelamento` WHERE 1 = 1       5   5   0

5   SELECT `Tpagamento`.`id`, `Tpagamento`.`nome` FROM `tereza`.`tpagamentos` AS `Tpagamento` WHERE 1 = 1       4   4   0

6   SELECT `Tpagamento`.`id`, `Tpagamento`.`nome`, `Tpagamento`.`created`, `Tpagamento`.`modified` FROM `tereza`.`tpagamentos` AS `Tpagamento` WHERE `Tpagamento`.`id` = 5 LIMIT 1      1   1   0
```

Comment: Show the generated SQL queries

Comment: 3 Importants questions: Why I can list if displayField = id? Why I CAN'T list if displayField = 'nome'? Why I cannot list, but I can read(null,$id)?

Comment: I solved my problem: In database.php I setted 'encoding' => 'utf8'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Config/database.php I setted: 'encoding' => 'utf8'

The reason to work In one table and not another is because in one table (tpagamentos) I have special characters and in another not (parcelamentos).

Answer (score 1):

To show two fields in a list use the following syntax:

```
$this->Parcelamento->find('list', array('fields' => array('id', 'other_field_name')));
```

Comment: In the Config/database.php I setted: 'encoding' => 'utf8'

The reason to work In one table and not another is because in one table (tpagamentos) I have special characters and in another not (parcelamentos).